# Eclipse Maven projects: A & B depend on C, but B gives classpath error whilst A works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I am a newbie when it comes to Maven, and so really struggling to solve the following problem because a colleague with real knowledge in this area has moved onto fresh pastures. Would really appreciate pointers to where I might be going wrong; I realise there must be lots of questions on StackOverflow about Maven & Eclipse classpaths, but having searched some of them, I need to ask in my own terms because of my lack of experience - sorry.

Some files are attached which I hope will be enough to form the equivalent of an SSCCE in pure Maven POM terms. The Java itself is irrelevant and subject to obvious confidentiality, but I can provide more info if needed.

So I have a small Maven project providing my own API for a third-party software protection dongle (DinKey, from Microcosm). The project is called dinkeypro with half a dozen of my classes which reference the manufacturer's class that reads/writes the dongle, namely DinkeyPro.class. This class is held inside DinkeyPro.JAR, which I reference as a dependency using a SystemPath and, as you can see from the following POM, I've tried two different SystemPath specs. Just for reference, note that the manufacturer requires the package structure for the class file to be:

```
uk/microcosm/dinkeydongle/DinkeyPro.class
```

Here is the POM for dinkeypro, with irrelevant dependencies removed for brevity/readability:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>dinkeypro</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DinkeyPro API</name>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>dinkeyjar</groupId>
       <artifactId>dinkeyjar</artifactId>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <!--<systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\DinkeyPro.jar</systemPath>-->
       <systemPath>C:\Dev\core_dinkeypro\src\main\resources\DinkeyPro.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Access to the dongle API is required from two other Maven projects, 'client' and 'server'. They both appear to specify the exact same Maven dependency on dinkeypro (see POMs below) although, admittedly, client and server are structured differently in terms of folders (server uses the more recognisable src/main/java paradigm but the client does not, and I'm wondering if this is the source of the problem.

What happens is that the client project runs and successfully reads the dongle via my API, whilst the server throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/microcosm/dinkeydongle/DinkeyPro
    at com.xyz.dinkeypro.SoftwareProtectionReadOnlyAgent.isProtectionDevicePresent(SoftwareProtectionReadOnlyAgent.java:73)
    at com.xyz.soft.ServerApp.initialize(ServerApp.java:1200)
    at com.xyz.soft.ServerApp.main(ServerApp.java:310)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.microcosm.dinkeydongle.DinkeyPro
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Here is the POM for client, which runs OK:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz.soft</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>client</name>
  <description>client</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${basedir}/target-resource</directory>
                      <filtering>true</filtering>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                      </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${basedir}/target-resource</directory>
                      <filtering>false</filtering>
                      <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                  <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                  </delimiters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>client</finalName>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.xyz.client.ClientApp</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>dinkeypro</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the POM for the server which has the classpath problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz.soft</groupId>
  <artifactId>server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>server</name>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>

          <execution>
            <id>additional-target-resources</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </resource>
              </resources>
              <delimiters>
                <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
              </delimiters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>run</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.xyz.server.ServerApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>ebmsCore</finalName>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.xyz.server.ServerApp</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>dinkeypro</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've examined the content of both the built client and server JAR files. They both contain DinkeyPro.JAR at the root of their own JAR, and both can navigate from the root to com.xyz.dinkeypro.

So, confusion reigns. Can anyone shed any light on what I've done wrong ? As you can see, I am valiantly trying to keep with Maven, simply so that future changes to dinkeypro API can just roll through to client and server (and any other projects that may need it one day...). However, if this gets to be too much of a minefield, I may just have to place a copy of DinkeyPro.JAR in the resources folder of the server project so that I can move on.

Many thanks

Comment: What's the *exact*, complete error message? What you've written, "classpath not found", doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @nitind   Apologies, I have edited my original post to include the full error message.